# How to print just the first letters of each word?

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm creating a quiz for my GCSE where a person is given the musical and the first letters of the song, they then must guess the entire song. The part I'm having trouble with is getting the initials of the song. I'm also using a CSV file.

So far I have the code below, but it only lets me print the first letter of the first word.

```
title_split = title.split() 
    for title in title_split:
        i = title[0]
        print(musical, i.upper())
```

For example if I have `Sincerely Me from Dear Evan Hansen`, it would currently print, `"Dear Evan Hansen, S"` instead of `"Dear Evan Hansen, S M"`

Comment: `print(musical, end = ' '`) before the loop, then just `print(i.upper())` in the loop

Comment: or better `print(musical, ' '.join(i[0].upper() for i in title.split())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
 title_split = title.split()     
 new=[]    
 for title in title_split:    
     letter=title[0].upper()    
     new.append(letter)    
 ans=" ".join(new)     
 print(musical+",",ans)
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Hiya, I was wondering if you could explain the function of ans?

Comment: Sure. Basically ans is just a string variable which stored the value of the first letters of title namely S M

Comment: ok sorry. i will try to be careful next time .thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. It schould work.

```
 title_split = title.split() 
 for title in title_split:
     i = title[0]
     print(musical, ' '.join(i[0].upper() for i in title.split())
```

EDIT: if this is not what you looking for, please comment and provide some more info about what you looking for so I can edit.

Comment: i tried this and on paper it seems to work but it just telling me i have an invalid syntax

Comment: probably you just need to format your code.  I did a little change, so try now.

Comment: The sintax error should be shown in editor, so it should not be hard to solve it. If you cant solve, please send some screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can see this exapmle help you to solve problem:

```
words = ["Daniel","Nashyl","Orla", "Simone","Zakaria"]
for word in words:
   print word[:1]
```